# How to add client side validation before execute asynctask?

Tags: android, validation, authentication

Hello I am new to android,in my app I have Login page and it works fine with my response but I want to add something like this,if my user name and password edittext is blank and user click on login button it should show message instead of start async task.

public class LoginPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

```
private Button btn;
private EditText user;
private EditText pass;


// Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManager session;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
//JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private Button btn1;
private String userid;

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "xxxxx";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status";
private static final String TAG_LOGIN = "login";
private static String TAG_USERID="user_login_id";
private static final String TAG_SESSION="session";
String session_id="";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginmailid);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginpwd);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);



}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
        if(user.equals(null) || pass.equals(null))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Session ID : " + session_id);
        session.createLoginSession(session_id);
        System.out.println(session);
        break;
        }

    case R.id.btnreg:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationForm.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
            break;
    }

}
```

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask {

```
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginPage.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Login..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
         try {
             //Building Parameters


             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", "apps"));

             Log.d("request!", "starting");
             // getting product details by making HTTP request
             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                 LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

             //check your log for json response
             Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

             JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
             final String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
             session_id = jobj.getString("user_login_id");
             System.out.println("Session ID : " + session_id);
             System.out.println("MSG : " + msg);

             runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() 
             {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            });
             return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);


             //JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("login");

            //System.out.println(arr.toString());
            //JSONObject arr1  = new JSONObject(json);
            //String ss=arr1.getString("status");
            //System.out.println(ss);
            //System.out.println(arr1.getString("status"));
             //String date = jObj.getString("status");



         }catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted


        pDialog.dismiss();
         if(file_url.equals("success")) {

                 session.createLoginSession(session_id);
                // Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                 Intent i = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                 i.putExtra("id", session_id);
                 System.out.println("Session Id : >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + session_id);
                 startActivity(i);

             }else{
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
}}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,

```
 if(user.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && pass.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
        {
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Session ID : " + session_id);
        session.createLoginSession(session_id);
        System.out.println(session);
        break;
        }
        else
        {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Why should this question be upvoted? And single char usernames and passwords are ok?

Answer (score 0):

try it this way...

```
case R.id.login:
        if(user.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || pass.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Session ID : " + session_id);
        session.createLoginSession(session_id);
        System.out.println(session);
        break;
        }
```